# is DWR (direct web remoting) a dead project?

Tags: dwr

Is DWR a dead project?  It does not appear to be under active development.  The latest 3.0 release appears to be stalled.  I'm specifically wondering if there are going to be maintenance releases of DWR 1.x or 2.x or is 3.0 is ever going to be released.

BTW.  I asked this question on one of the DWR mailing lists and did not get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the 3.0 version is taking a while to get released, but it is nonetheless very stable.
We are using it in our production environment and we do did encounter any issue so far (2+ years in use).
Important issues on 2.0.X are fixed BTW. (seems that currently there are no major issues on 2.0.X).

> BTW. I asked this question on one of the DWR mailing lists and did not get a response.

We had issues before (other version) and those were handler very quick.

Update Dec/2015: V3.0.1 released

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it, I have used DWR like a year back and there is no release since then.
Their version 3 is still on RC (release candidate) and from my understanding of versioning, it is not stable or a general acceptance.
I would say move on... pass DWR.  Pass Java too if you can ;)

Comment: -1  No need to bash Java.  I guess you'd choose Ruby to write software for a car?  If you want to share this sentiment, find a better place to do it than on an answer to a question about a Java library.

Comment: I don't think an opinion deserves a negative point here... Especially one that is held by a significant proportion of the developer community, as controversial as it might be... Wrong or misleading answers deserve that in my opinion...